# Trying to simplify a JS document

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm doing is a dynamic figure, for example, showing the weather in each city. for example:

Comment: I would recommend submitting this question to the Code Review Stack Exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions about bugs, not for general code advice

Comment: @Hamms This probably isn't complete enough for CR. Read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: It looks pretty simple to me. You could replace the `for` loop with `$.each()`, but I don't see much other opportunity for improvement.

Comment: New York in the winter gets below freezing.  That would likely mess up your graph.

Comment: Thank you very much for the varied ideas. How can i change color of specific graph text, for example: 90C to white instead of black?

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really need any simplification, but it might be easier to follow if you divide the operations up into separate steps (using functions).

```js
var weather = {
  getTemps: function(){
    return $("#in1").val().split(" ");
  },
  buildGraph: function(temps){
    var a = 60, graph="", hi = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<temps.length; i++) {
        hi = temps[i] * 5;
        graph += '<rect width="50px" class="grp" id="id' + temps.lengtg + '" height="' + hi + '" x="' + a + '" data-temp="' + temps[i] + '"/>';
        a += 110;
    }
    return graph;
  },
  initMouseEvents: function(){
    $("rect").mouseover(function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY;
        var temp = $(this).attr('data-temp');
        $("#temp").text(temp + "c");

        $("#temp").css("left", x + "px");
        $("#temp").css("top", y-45 + "px").show();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $("#temp").hide();
    });
  },
  init: function(){
    var temps = this.getTemps();
    var graph = this.buildGraph(temps);
    $("#svg1").html(graph);
    this.initMouseEvents();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  weather.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="fg1">
   <input type="hidden" value="70 80 35 20 110" id="in1" />
   <figcaption> weather</figcaption>
   <svg width="500px" height="230px" id="svg1" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is closer to the result you are expecting.

Important to see that 'y' coordinate must be inverted, because of the SVG frame.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (grp) {
            updateSVG();
            $("#update").click(function (e) {
                updateSVG();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $(document.body).on('mouseover','svg .temp', function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-index");
                var temp = $(this).attr("data-temp") + "C";
                $("#text-" + id).html(temp).show();
            });
            $(document.body).on('mouseout','svg .temp', function() {
                var id= $(this).attr("data-index");
                $("#text-" + id).hide();
            });
            function updateSVG() {
                $("#svg1").html("");
                var temps = $("#in1").val().split(" ");
                var content = "";
                for (var i in temps) {
                    var temp = temps[i];
                    var x = i * 110;
                    var y = (230 - temp);
                    var elem = '<rect style="fill:rgb(0,0,200)" class="temp" width="50px" class="grp" id="id' + i + '" height="' + (temp) + '" x="' + x + '" y="' + y + '" data-index="' + i + '" data-temp="' + temp + '"/>';
                    var text = '<text style="display:none;" id="text-' + i + '" x="' + x + '" y="' + (y - 20) + '" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">Hello, out there</text>';
                    content += elem + text;
                }
                $("#svg1").html(content);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <figure id="fg1">
        <label>Type here the temperatures</label>
        <input id="in1" type="text" value="70 80 35 20 110" />
        <button id="update">Update graph</button>
        <figcaption> weather</figcaption>
        <svg width="500px" height="230px" id="svg1" />
    </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I got a "-1" because I tried to help in a question that doesn't fit to this forum?

Comment: Everyone thinks they're the police around here, don't let it bother you.